# Yii2 Gii not showing Generate button

Tags: model, generator, yii2, gii

I got the Gii module working but when I try to create a Model using the generator, I click preview, the page refreshes but nothing happens - no generate button, no warning, no error and nothing in the logs.

Any advice or comment very appreciated.

EDIT : Preview is null and it seems to be the issue. Could anyone post what he has in the debugger ? thanks.

[image: Preview is null !??]

Comment: You are working in localhost and you are an admin user?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am lol

Answer (score 2):

You just have to first click **Preview**, it will show you which files it will build. Then, click **Generate.**

After you click Preview, following table will acquire **under** the Preview, then you have to choose the files to build:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer bfcm, I did... The page just reloads and nothing happens

Comment: I see. That's not the normal behavior of Gii. Unfortunately can not help further except advicing to try reinstall Gii/Yii.

Answer (score 0):

Ok fixed it.

If you have such problem open /vendor/yiisoft/yii2-gii/views/default/view/view.php and append a value attribute to the buttons.

Works like a charm.

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: It's just a temporary hack, you will lose these changes on the next `composer update`. Remember, you should not modify any files in`vendor` folder.

Comment: And as for the code - it's better to insert it as text instead of image.

Comment: Thank you arogachev. You're absolutely right, this is a temporary hack but necessary if you want to use the generator at this stage... Unless I absolutely have to, I won't change any vendor files.